# Drupal: - Field Info API as REST

Tags: rest, drupal-7, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

We would like to get label for the field.

As per previous question: [How do I get a field label by the field name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38115/how-do-i-get-a-field-label-by-the-field-name)?

But I need to get this through the REST API of Drupal.

Could anyone please suggest what should be the approach to use the Field API from as REST

Answer (score 1):

I can get values through the REST API.

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_menu().
 */
function sample_menu() {
    $items['api/sample'] = array(
        'title' => 'Sample REST API',
        'page callback' => 'sample_api',
        'access callback' => true
    )
}

/**
 * callback function for /api/sample
 */
function sample_api() {
   $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input'); // if you want to get post data
   drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

   // set values from Fields and so on

   drupal_json_output(array("output" => 'this is rest api sample module output.', 'id' => 12345));
   drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: @Banng If you resolve this issue, I want you to close this issue.